# Potassium permanganate to analyze iron compounds

Tags: titration

In my lab, I used potassium permanganate in order to analyze the amount of iron in a compound with iron in the +2 oxidation state using titration. My question is how would this analysis be different if we were analyzing iron in a different oxidation state like +3?

Comment: There would simply be no reaction observable. In my introductory lab, we were given an iron(III) sample to titrate and the first step was to reduce it to iron(II).

Comment: Assuming you have enough sample, first simply titrate to find how much iron(II) you have. Then convert all iron(III) to iron(II). Titrate again, and the difference you find is iron(III). (Not sure how reliable this is though.)

Answer (score 1):

The *Standard Methods for the Examination of Water and Wastewater 3500-Fe* is a method for determining total $\ce{Fe}$, $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ and $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ in water using a colorimetric detection technique.  As in your titrimetric method, this method can only directly measure $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$.  In order to measure $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ (the only other reasonably stable oxidation state of $\ce{Fe}$) you must first reduce the $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ to $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$.  I believe you could use the same reduction technique to prepare a solution of $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ for your titration method.

The procedure sited above states that:

> "[the $\ce{Fe}$ in the sample is] reduced to the ferrous state by boiling
>   with acid and hydroxylamine."

The hydroxylamine solution is prepared by dissolving 10 g $\ce{NH2OH⋅HCl}$ in 100 mL water.  50 mL of the water sample is acidified with 2.0 mL of concentrated $\ce{HCl}$, and 1 mL of the $\ce{NH2OH}$ solution is added to the acidified water sample.

As $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ species are frequently insoluble, the procedure described above calls for boiling the solution down to 15-20 mL to get all of the iron both dissolved and reduced before bringing the solution back up to 50 mL for analysis.  If the solution were prepared from a soluble $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ salt like $\ce{FeCl3}$ for example, simply boiling the solution for 5 minute or so would likely be sufficient.

So, I suspect you could measure the $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ in your solution using your titration method *if* you first reduced the $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ to $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ using the hydroxylamine reduction described above.